# Prove that a $\mathbb R^2$ function is convex

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, convex-analysis

> Suppose that, for each $x,y$, such that $f(x)\geq f(y)$ one of the following condition must hold:
>
> 1. $f(ax+(1-a)y)\geq f(y)$ for all $a\in(0,1)$
> 2. $f(ax+(1-a)y)\leq f(x)$ for all $a\in(0,1)$
>
> $f$ is smooth. Can we claim that $f$ is either a quasi-convex function or a quasi-concave function?

---

Basically, we want to show that, **either (1) holds for all pair $x,y$**, or (2) holds for all pair $x,y$.

The domain of $f$ is $\mathbb R^N$ but I think we could try $N=1$ or $2$ first.

I try to find the set $S=\{x||f(x)=f(y)\}$. The boundary is smooth. Suppose that property (1) hold for two points $a,b\in S$, then property (1) must hold for an open neighborhood of $a,b$. Since $f$ is smooth, the neighborhood of neighborhood can cover all points of $S$ if $S$ is connected. This can be done because, in my humble opinion, if $f$ is smooth, then $S$ must be closed.

Is this approach plausible?

Comment: It would be nice if you would describe the domain of $f$

Answer (score 1):

This approach is not possible.
If $A$ is an open set, then $A$ is also a neighborhood of $A$.
Thus one cannot hope to reach larger sets just by "taking neighborhoods".

Comment: In my humble opinion, if $f$ is smooth, then $S$ must be closed.